# '@RequiredArgsConstructor' and 'MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I have multiple DTO objects that all look like this:

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeDTO {
  private final String someProperty;
}
```

These DTO objects are accepted in various `RestController` methods:

```
@RestController
public void InvitationController {

  @PostMapping
  public String create(@RequestBody InvitationCreationDTO invitationCreationDTO) {
    // some logic
    return "ok";
  }

}
```

Jackson does not have an issue deserializing json to these classes, except for the following one:

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InvitationCreationDTO {
  private final String emailAddress;
}
```

When Jackson tries to deserialize the following JSON:

```js
{ "emailAddress" : "some@email.com" }
```

This error is thrown:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `my.package.InvitationCreationDTO` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1429) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1059) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3258) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
```

It works, however, when I remove the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and create one myself:

```
@Getter
public class InvitationCreationDTO {
  private final String emailAddress;

  @JsonCreator
  public InvitationCreationDTO(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
  }
}
```

Why does this class need this, but my other DTO classes (that have the same format) not?

Comment: Try adding another `@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = PRIVATE)`.

Comment: I'll try that, but howcome jackson does not complain about other DTO classes that look like this?

Comment: Without an access to your codebase, I'm a bit clueless indeed :/ I guess the usages differ a tad somehow? Do you use both DTOs in the exact same way, e.g. via `@RequestBody`, same request `Content-Type`, same `ObjectMapper`, etc.?

Comment: @sp00m, yes, all DTO objects are used in the same way. I have many `SomeCreationDTO` classes that all work fine, except for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@NoArgsConstructor` to your `InvitationCreationDTO` class

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InvitationCreationDTO {
  private final String emailAddress;
}
```

Comment: Adding `@NoArgsConstructor` to a class with a `final` field does not work.

Comment: What you mean does not work? `@NoArgsConstructor` creates constructor with empty arguments. It doesn't care how many final/non final fields you have.

Comment: And actually why its final, did you try to remove final?

Comment: A property that is marked `final` needs to be initialized at instantiation. A no-args constructor will not instantiate it, which is why the compiler complains when adding this annotation. The fields are final because the classes are immutable.

Comment: @GigaKokaia it's a good practice to finalise your fields, it allows immutability, which itself solves quite many other issues :) You can force a `@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)` though. I don't recall exactly the output of this one, must be rather hacky, but I remember it solving a similar issue I had.